# Finding correlation between location based data

Tags: python, mysql, sql, tableau-api

I am trying to find the correlation between some location-based data in a MySQL db where we store info on clients and partners. Every client has a field for their respective `geo_zip_code` and `geo_region` and so does every partner. When a client enters our system they receive offers from three different partners. I want to see if a client is more likely to accept an offer where the partner is in either the same `geo_zip_code` or `geo_region` based off of the `geo_zip_code` or `geo_region` field of the table with the matches between the client and one of the three partners. However, I do not know where to start in order to accomplish this. If possible, how do I do this in MySQL? Otherwise, if you do not wish to thoroughly answer, you are more than welcome to direct me in a direction where I can find info on how to solve this. Also, if it is possible to do this in either Tableau or Python, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: We would have to know whether the offers the clients accept is stored and where in the database structure that the information would exist. Regardless, you will need to find some way to relate the accepted offers to both the clients and the partners in order to get accurate data on this problem.

Comment: Edward, both an offers table and matches table exists, which I forgot to include. Both tables carry the ID of the client and the partner. This means that the tables with the matches should be the one to find the relation between the client and partner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be a good starting point. Of course, I don't have your table names.

```
DECLARE @total_matches INT 
DECLARE @non_matches INT 
DECLARE @region_or_zip_matches INT 
-- this will return a count of all matches 
SELECT @total_matches = COUNT(m.'8')
FROM Matches as m 
-- this will return a count of matches where there is no zip/region match 
SELECT @non_matches = COUNT('8') 
FROM Matches  AS m 
INNER JOIN Clients AS c 
    ON c.client_id = m.client_id
INNER JOIN Partners AS p 
    ON p.partner_id = m.partner_id
WHERE 
AND c.geo_region IS NOT NULL --not null's may be unnecessary based on column criteria. 
AND p.geo_region IS NOT NULL 
AND c.geo_zip_code IS NOT NULL 
AND p.geo_zip_code IS NOT NULL 
AND (c.geo_region != p.geo_region
AND c.geo_zip_code != p.geo_zip_code)

SET @region_or_zip_matches = @total_matches - @non_matches

SELECT (CAST(@region_or_zip_matches AS FLOAT) / CAST(@total_matches AS FLOAT) * 100;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Edward! That was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the comments to clarify as well.